# How can I view and use Font Awesome icons in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: fonts, adobe, adobe-illustrator, font-awesome

I am trying to do some web design mockups for my development team using font awesome for icons, and not all the icons show when I select the font.

How can I do this and be able to view all the icons within Adobe Illustrator? (is this even possible)?

Comment: [Font awesome icons in SVG, EPS etc](http://www.flaticon.com/packs/font-awesome)

Answer (score 9):

print this page [fonts](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) as PDF file and then open it with adobe ;)

Comment: Question is closed, but if anyone needs a ready-to-use PDF, here you'll find it:
http://www.wn6.co.uk/font-awesome-vector-pdf/

Comment: Here you go! - http://www.flaticon.com/packs/font-awesome